# Is there any indication that the the other ship in "Night Terrors" was Tamarian?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

'Cos both "Night Terrors" and "Darmok" involve a completely metaphorical language.  I know this is not a lot to go on.

On the other hand, the aliens in "Night Terrors" were able to communicate telepathically with Deanna, and clearly the Tamarians in Darmok did not (would not or could not).

Comment: was the language in Night Terrors fully metaphorical or was that particular message crafted to be as universally interpretable as possible? I don't recall it being said that the entire language was metaphor

Comment: I don't think it was a ship. It appeared to be an energy being(s). At any rate, you may be guilty of Small Universe Thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original screenplay would indicate that the *"other vessel"* was some kind of energy-based lifeform.

> EXT. SPACE - THE ENTERPRISE (OPTICAL):
>
> grabs power, accelerates, skims through the last sparks
>   of the diminishing explosion... directly into the
>   center of the rift...
>
> And passing it, going the opposite direction... **a
>
>   shapeless mass... a sparkling energy field... the
>
>   other ship.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Night Terrors - Screenplay.](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/191.txt)</sup></sub>

Since the [Tamarians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Children_of_Tama) are neither [energy-based](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tamarian_deep_space_cruiser), nor obviously telepathic, it seems highly unlikely (to the point of impossibility) that it's one of their vessels.

[image]

Comment: Hadn't thought about the Tamarians not being telepathic at all. Also didn't remember the alien ship being pure energy. Upvote.

Comment: I fail to see any indication in the cited excerpt of the screenplay that the "other vessel" (which is called "the other ship" there) was meant to be an "energy-based lifeform". And, furthermore, as far as alien ships on Star Trek that are only seen in the form of vague lights go, this is one of the least "shapeless" examples.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - My first thought was that the rift had to be a rift *to somewhere* with the "shapeless mass" being on the other side of said rift, existing in a world of pure energy.

Answer (score 5):

### No, there is no indication that the other ship was Tamarian.

The language used, *"eyes in the dark"* and *"one moon circles"*, are telepathic messages as explained by Deanna Troi. There is no indication that the aliens in the other ship literally send these words. For all we know they telepathically send images of the binary star system, which Deanna "sees" as two eyes in the dark, and a schematic depiction of a hydrogen atom, which Deanna "sees" as a planetary system.

Since we do not know if words or images were telepathically sent, we have no way of knowing what the aliens' actual language is, or if they have a (spoken) language at all.